# Probability of an alternating series of random numbers in the range $[1,N]$ whose sum adds up to the desired number $N$?

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose any number $N$ can be represented as an alternating series of random numbers in the range $[1,N]$ whose sum adds up to the desired number $N$.

For [example](https://trinket.io/python3/efc8580864), let $N=5$, then generating random numbers in the range $[1,5]$ gives

$$4-2+4-1$$

Plotting this shows it took $4$ random terms to reach the desired number $5$

[image: sum0]

Another run showing over $60$ terms

[image: sum1]

The last run showing $7500+$ terms

[image: sum2]

Expressing this in mathematical notation

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i-1} a_i$$

where $a_i \in {1, 2, ..., N}$ is random.

**Question**

Is there a way to determine the probability of this method converging to the desired number $N$?

All tests eventually converged but took much longer as $N$ increased.

Got the idea from reading about a [Random Walk--2-Dimensional](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk2-Dimensional.html)

> Amazingly, it has been proven that on a two-dimensional lattice, a
> random walk has unity probability of reaching any point (including the
> starting point) as the number of steps approaches infinity.

Comment: As a hint, try to show that both $0 \leq S_n < N$ and $N < S_n \leq 2N$ happen for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$.  (this is an application of the simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$).  From here, show that $S_n=N$ for some $n$ with probability $1$ by applying the former result along with a geometric random variable you may define.